# Can not find mongos

Tags: mongodb, installation

I have installed the MongoDB 2.6 Standard and want to try to setup a shard cluster.
But I can't find the mongos in the bin-directory.

[image]

Any suggestions ?

Ciao, Andre

Comment: No idea of which installer or package you used, but zip files from http://www.mongodb.org/downloads do have mongos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely installed from the `.msi` using the `Typical` setup. You need to either install the `Complete` setup or go through `Custom` and select the `Router` feature.